# Table sorting in meteor

Tags: meteor

In my `meteor app` I need to implement table sorting. Now what I'm doing is setting a `session variable` for each coloumn and toggling its value based on the item to be sort.
Can any one suggest a better option ?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend **Tabular**. It takes the JQuery DataTables library and makes it Meteor friendly. It has sorting and searching built-in. It supports custom cells and is feature rich. I use it with large collections and it is fast and CPU friendly.

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular/

Answer (score 2):

have you tried Reactive Table?

https://github.com/ecohealthalliance/reactive-table

Comment: Unfortunately I had a bad experience with reactive-table. I needed a couple of features and it was too inflexible for my case

Comment: I need to warn people about reactive-table. It's feature rich and great, but I had terrible scaling issues with it after having >100,000 items across a couple collections. The CPU on the server would spike to 100% and then oscillate from 5% to 50% every few seconds with just one user. A few more users and it will be constant 100%. I found meteor-tabular and covers most of the reactive-table features, but most importantly doesn't spike the CPU at all.